# Best way to access SQLite database on AWS EC2 server from iOS app?

Tags: php, ios, sqlite, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a web server set up on an EC2 instance where I have a SQLite database stored. For testing purposes, I currently have a PHP file that I can hit by sending an NSURLRequest to `http://<my-instance-ip>/foo.php`, where the script will access the SQLite database and return the information in JSON. Would I want to do the same thing in a live application or am I thinking of this completely the wrong way? I'm new to AWS so I'm not too sure about how these services are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the database is for all your app users, you should use mysql or other full functional database, and use php to write web services.

If the database is for a single user, you can just store the sqlite data in the device, and use fmdb to access it

Comment: The database is for all users to read from. So if I use MySQL and I use a file called foo.php to read from it, should I access it from the app using its public ip in the form of `http://<ip>/foo.php`?

Comment: You can do that, but what you can do better is to create proper web service for your database

Comment: There're a lot of PHP framework, e.g Zend Framework which you can use to write web service

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too well-versed in web development, but users will only be reading from the database via the PHP file, so won't the PHP file serve as the proper web service? Unless I'm not understanding what you mean by web service.

Comment: the database could have a lot of tables, and each table could have multiple columns. How are you going to return the whole database in a single call?

Comment: I suppose you can create different service calls like: http://yourdomain/foo.php?method=getUsers to just return the users, http://yourdomain/foo.php?method=getPictuers to just return all the pics, something like that

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking in larger terms, but mine just has one table with no more than a few hundred entries. I simply create an array of dictionaries and return it in JSON. Hence why I didn't think it necessary to use MySQL since it's a fairly small dataset.

Comment: sqlite database is just a file, there'll be problems when multiple users try to access the database at the same time

Comment: Ah I see, then MySQL it is.

Comment: yep, then just use a single php to read data from mysql database